# How to get returned object from JPA EntityManager as customized bean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to join 3 tables to get required info using `entityManager.createQuery`.

Code littlepet as follows:

```
List<Object[]> o=entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u.loginId,ui.emailId,u.userId,ui.firstName,up.password,ui.phoneNunber,u.roleTypeId"  + " From Users as u,UserInfo ui, UserPassword as up where u.userId = up.userId "    + "AND u.userId=ui.userId").getResultList();
```

I have a bean with the above returned fields `UserDetails`.

```
public class UserDetails
{
    String LoginId;
    String Email;
    String UserId;
    String FirstName;
    String Password;
    String Mobile;
    String RoleTypeId;
    int Status;

getters() & setters()
}
```

But when I am trying to use `List` of `UserDetails` instead `List` of `Object[]` it says `ClassCastException`.

How to get/convert the returned object with customized bean?

Comment: hmm I don't know the answer but wouldn't it be better to use joins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 List<UserDetails> o=entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new package.UserDetails( u.loginId,ui.emailId,u.userId,ui.firstName,up.password,ui.phoneNunber,u.roleTypeId)"  + " From Users as u,UserInfo ui, UserPassword as up where u.userId = up.userId "    + "AND u.userId=ui.userId").getResultList();
```

You need to have constructor with parameters in the same order as the fields are selected in the query, thus **UserDetails(loginId, emailId, userId, firstName, password, phoneNunber, roleTypeId)**

Or you can use your code and then write a converter which converts an array of objects into **UserDetails**.

```
 List<Object[]> retrievedObjects = //yourCode.
 for (Object[] objs : retrievedObjects) {
      //write convert method which populates **UserDetails** fields from the objects.
      UserDetails ud = convert(objs);
 }
```

Comment: I tried the first 1 but it says:
ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (default task-30)  Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class

second 1 will work definitely work.

Comment: @Joe You need to add a constructor to the `UserDetails`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. Constructor with parameters in the same order as the fields are selected in the query, thus **UserDetails(loginId, emailId, firstName, ...)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use a result transformer. Result transformer is a Hibernate feature (not JPA). So you need to use `Session` or `Query` from Hibernate.

Something like this:

```
List<UserDetails> result = entityManager.createQuery(
  "SELECT u.loginId as loginId, ui.emailId as emailId ..."
).unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class)
 .setResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(UserDetails.class))
 .list();
```

You need to have aliases in the HQL: `u.loginId as loginId` and corresponding properties in the `UserDetails`:

```
class UserDetails
{

  private String loginId;

  public String getLoginId() {
    return loginId;
  }

  public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
    this.loginId = loginId;
  }

}
```

Examples of transformers:
http://jpwh.org/examples/jpwh2/jpwh-2e-examples-20151103/examples/src/test/java/org/jpwh/test/querying/advanced/TransformResults.java